# Join two tables into third

Tags: sqlite

I have two tables with some columns common. I want to join those tables and form third table, which is combination of two tables.
Example:

```
Table 1
```

A B C D E F

```
Table 2
```

A B C G H I

Expected Output:

```
Table 3
```

A B C D E F G H I

can anyone suggest me how to do this?

Comment: How are the records in the two tables related? What should happen for records that do not have a corresponding record in the other table?

Answer (score 0):

You can use join for this operation.

```
CREATE TABLE table3 AS SELECT t1.A, t1.B, t1.C, t1.D, t1.E, t1.F, t2.G, t2.H, t2.I
FROM Table1 t1 LEFT JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.A = t2.A AND t1.B = t2.B AND t1.C = t2.C
```

This query will give you  A B C D E F G H I output, if you want to create a new table

Comment: It's giving null for all the columns from table 2

Comment: Are you sure you have appropriate matching data in table 2? Because left join does that, when there is no data in the second table, it fills the resulting columns with NULLs.